# Using Active Directory to determine what is displayed on a page

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I am rather new to C#.  I want to display one set of fields if the user who is logged in is a member of the Administration Board and another set of fields if the user is not a member of the Administration Board.

The manager has instructed me to use Active Directory to do this.

Is there an example someone can point me to that I can review?

Is there a way for me to write a page (just for my own review) that will display all the  user groups this organization has in Active Directory?

Comment: What version of .NET are you using? The method in which you query Active Directory will change based on the version of .NET that you use.

Comment: I am using version 4.0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one way of doing an Active Directory query that gets all domain users, a specific user's groups, and whether a user belongs to a group:

```
public static List<string> DomainUsers
{
    get
    {
        List<string> users = new List<string>();

        using (PrincipalContext ctx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, "domain"))
        {
            // find user by display name
            UserPrincipal user = new UserPrincipal(ctx);
            PrincipalSearcher search = new PrincipalSearcher(user);

            search.FindAll().Cast<UserPrincipal>().ToList().ForEach(u => users.Add(u.SamAccountName));
        }
        return users;
    }
}

/// <summary>
/// Gets all associated group names for current user on the current domain
/// </summary>
/// <returns></returns>
public static List<string> GetGroupNames(string username)
{
    var pc = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, "domain");
    var src = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(pc, username).GetGroups(pc);
    var result = new List<string>();
    src.ToList().ForEach(sr => result.Add(sr.SamAccountName));
    return result;
}

public static bool UserBelongsToGroup(string group)
{
    PrincipalContext pc = new PrincipalContext((Environment.UserDomainName == Environment.MachineName ? ContextType.Machine : ContextType.Domain), Environment.UserDomainName);

    GroupPrincipal gp = GroupPrincipal.FindByIdentity(pc, group);
    UserPrincipal up = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(pc, Environment.UserName);
    return up.IsMemberOf(gp);
}
```

Please note that you will need to use the `System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement` namespace which can be found in the .NET 4.0 framework assemblies when adding a reference. You will need to be targetting .NET 4.0 to use this namespace.

Answer (score 0):

Use IsInRole() method. It is in System.Principle namespace - as far as I remember.